# K2 Activity Data field WorklistCriteria filter

Tags: k2

I need to create a criteria filter on an Activity data field, that may or may not exist for the process; however if the data field does not exist the criteria does not return the process. Is there a way to ignore the fact that the field does not exist in the criteria?

Alternatively, what other ways are there to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you using the UI to create the criteria, or the criteria API?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The Creiteria API: WorklistCriteria.AddFilterField(...)

Comment: Ok I have a hunch that using a filter like `(Field = "SomeValue" OR Field = NULL)` might work. I'm just busy verifying it; otherwise I will log a bug to get the `Exists` criteria comparison added.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. The NULL criteria don't work. You get an empty list back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried, firstly:

```
(ActivityData.CustomerName == "Bob" OR ActivityData.CustomerName == NULL)`
```

Secondly:

```
(ProcessFullName != "K2Project2\Process1" OR ActivityName != "DefaultActivity" OR ActivityData.CustomerName == "Bob")
```

Niether worked, this isn't possible today (*I have logged the bug*).

The only workaround available to you right now is to do two queries, the first with the field the second without. Add them to a single list, but before adding values from the second result-set check that each one does not have the field.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jonathan, and sorry for my late reply!